# returning a dictionary and assigning keys and values from text file

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, key

I am getting an error "list index out of range" for the line where I am trying to assign the keys and values for the dictionary. I am trying to name the item in the second row as the key and the first as the value. The text file I am importing looks like this:

A0101   Typhoid meningitis
A0102   Typhoid fever with heart involvement
A0103   Typhoid pneumonia
A0104   Typhoid arthritis

```
 def disease_to_code_dictionary() :
    
    infile = open("ICD10.txt","r")
    header_row = infile.readline() # skip the header row
    dictionary = {}
    for line in infile :
        cells = line.split("\t") # split by the tab character
        dictionary[cells[1]]=cells[0]
        if len(cells) >= 2 : # only if the line had a tab
            code = cells[0]
            disease = cells[1]
            disease = disease.lower() # lowercase
            disease = disease.replace("\"","") # remove all double quotes


    infile.close()
```

Comment: The error says _"list index out of range"_, so the error is that an index is bigger than a list. The line is `dictionary[cells[1]]=cells[0]`. The list is `cells`. The indexes are `0` and `1`. Does that explain it?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Yeah thats right. So I'm not sure what I'm missing when it comes to assigning the keys and values since I'm creating a dictionary. I thought 0 and 1 would identify the items in row 1 and row 2. Since the list has multiple lines, would I have to include more than just 0 and 1?

Comment: No, `cells` does not contain lines. You should use a debugger or at least `print` values of your variables to see what is going on. Try with `print(line)` and `print(cells)`.

Comment: ahh...I replaced 'cells' with 'line' in the dictionary[line[1]]=line[0] line. I think that was the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to split the lines on spaces and then join all the items from index `1` to the end of the list as the key and then index `0` as the value.

```
cell = line.strip("\n").split(" ")
dictionary[' '.join(cell[1:])] = cell[0]
```

I'm also updating this to use a [context manager](https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2016/03/07/python-with-context-managers/) to handle the file reading.

```py
def disease_to_code_dictionary():
    with open("ICD10.txt", "r") as infile:
        dictionary = {}
        for line in infile:
            cell = line.strip("\n").split(" ")
            dictionary[' '.join(cell[1:])] = cell[0]
    return dictionary
```